# Youtube API subscribers count not updating

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have explained about this problem via video please see the video here:

[Strange Problem About Youtube API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9YaNxJIK8I)

I am having a strange problem about youtube API . For example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/tryingtobesikh
```

the above api return with the subscribers count. But when someone subscribe , it doesnt update instantly after refresh. But the strange thing is , it updates when i press f5(refresh) two times at once. Don't know what is the problem, may be some cache prob? I am working on a script where i need to check if someone subscribed or not intantly. If the user subscribed do this , if didn't do something else. So  i need instant subscribers count changes.
Any type of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official YouTube API documentation does note that there may be delays with data updating:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Overview:

> Statistics, such as the number of times a video has been viewed or the
>   number of comments available for a video, are typically updated within
>   30 minutes to two hours after the upload completes. However, this
>   delay may be longer under heavy API server loads.
>
> On an ongoing basis, statistics for a video are typically updated
>   every 30 minutes to two hours. However, updates may occur less
>   frequently under heavy server loads or for videos that are viewed very
>   infrequently. In search feeds, updates to ratings and view counts
>   could take as long as a couple of weeks for infrequently viewed
>   videos.

On a side note;
I've only used the YouTube API once myself, but seen as you said you need to check if a user has subscribed to another user, maybe you could try looking into the activity feed API? as this contains information about recent subscriptions:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_activity_feeds